# Intersecting time slots

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on a booking system which works around the user selecting a time slot and I am stuck attempting to check for overlapping bookings.

I am attempting to create a function which returns all the available time slots. I have an array called `bookings` which are the bookings for that day, and I have an array called `slots`.

I have tried looping through the arrays and attempting this:

`if (slot.start > booking.dateStart.clone().addMinutes(-30) && slot.end < booking.dateEnd.clone().addMinutes(30))`

To check for any overlap, and if there is I splice the slot from the array. I need to leave a 30 minute gap between each booking so that is why I am adding minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula to find overlapping time periods is

```
start1 <= end2 && end1 >= start2
```

If that is true, then the periods do overlap. If you need to leave a 30 minute gap, just add that to the comparison of `end1` and `start2`.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss this. Been up all night writing complicated solutions to a problem that can be solved as simply as this. Thanks alot!